# Set the browser window size (or maximize it) in the test runner configuration file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests, webdriver-io

Using webdriverio, I need to maximize the browser window (all, or per capability).

I know about [`windowHandleSize`](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/windowHandleSize.html), and I could use it, but I'm using the test runner and I would rather do it in the configuration file, for all tests.

Is there any way of doing this in the [test runner's configuration file](http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/configurationfile.html)? I could do it in the `before` hook by using the global `browser` object, but was wondering if there's any dedicated setting for this.

Thanks!

Comment: It is a single line command .

driver.manage().windows().maximize;

Answer (score 1):

i have used WebDriver in java but have not used WebDriverIO any way.
you can use 'client.windowHandleMaximize([windowHandle]);'

ref.
https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/lib/protocol/windowHandleMaximize.js

and

https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#dfn-maximize-window

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm using for now. I'm calling it in the global `before` hook, the one defined in the config file.